# How to get value of a text area using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fetch the text(Againnnn ??) from below html code.

```
<pre class="mentions-highlighter" role="presentation">Againnnn ??</pre>
<textarea class="mentions-input trans" placeholder="Add a comment..." style="height: 47px;" dir="ltr"></textarea>
```

I tried this but it didn't worked properly.

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('.mentions-input trans').value;
```

Comment: Tried this var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('.mentions-input trans').value;

Comment: you need to assign an ID to your element and then you can do `document.getElementById('YourID').innerHTM;`

Comment: @torazaburo The OP has commented in one of the existing answers that ID's cannot be added, hence my warning about using `getElementByClassName` and using `[0]` as that will get the first element of that class.

Comment: Correction on my comment. Try `var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('mentions-input trans')[0].value;` assuming this is the first element with that class name.

Comment: I have just noticed why people could find your question confusing. First you ask how to get the value of the text area but in your question description you say "I want to fetch the text(Againnnn ??) " Againnnn isn't in the text area, it's in the pre element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.getElementsByClassName with [0] to access the tag and then innerHTML to get the text value as in :

```
function myFunction() {
    var comment= document.getElementsByClassName("mentions-highlighter")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(comment);
}
```

This function will alert

```
"Againnnn ??"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple text() method to get text from one class to another class.
try to this script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.mentions-input').text($('.mentions-highlighter').text());
  });
</script>

<pre class="mentions-highlighter" role="presentation">Againnnn ??</pre>
<textarea class="mentions-input trans" placeholder="Add a comment..." style="height: 47px;" dir="ltr"></textarea>
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the existing answers and checking the tags. jQuery isn't tagged and you haven't made any attempt to point out the use of jQuery in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a **list** of elements, not a single one. Just do

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('mentions-input trans')[0].value
```

(Note the `[0]`.)

Comment: You have a period in front of `mentions-input trans`

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in `var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('.mentions-input trans').value;`

1. As @torazaburo says `getElementsByClassName` method returns list of elements and you may get any element by index
2. `getElementsByClassName` method gets classname argument, not a selector

Worked example:

```js
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('mentions-input trans')[0].value;
alert(comment);
```

```html
<pre class="mentions-highlighter" role="presentation">Againnnn ??</pre>
<textarea class="mentions-input trans" placeholder="Add a comment..." style="height: 47px;" dir="ltr">test value</textarea>
```